# Ajuste de líneas en synedit

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

Estoy utilizando el componente **synedit** en **Lazarus** y cuando una línea es más larga que el ancho de la ventana asignada al componente, desaparece por la derecha de la ventana.
Esto no sucede con el componente Tmemo

¿Es posible que cuando una línea es demasiado larga para presentarse en la ventana, el excedentea se muestre en la línea siguiente como es habitual en cualquier editor de texto?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El componente SynEdit de [este repositorio en github](https://github.com/SynEdit/SynEdit) tiene la propiedad **`WordWrap`** que, de ponerse a `True` tendría el comportamiento que describes.  Dado que SynEdit es generalmente usado para mostrar código fuente, dónde no suele verse este comportamiento, se entiende que la propiedad tenga el valor `False` por defecto.

```
  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    synEdit1.WordWrap := True;
  end;
```

Este cambio también puedes hacerlo en tiempo de diseño.

He visto que esta propiedad ha reportado algunos problemas en el pasado, que desconozco si están resueltos. Uno de ellos es que se describe en [esta pregunta de StackOverflow en Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54494905/255257), y en cuya [respuesta aceptada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54504439/255257) se explica que el mecanismo se basa en un *plugin* que, en ese momento (2019) tenía un bug y ofrece una posible solución.

Dado que es una característica que no utilizo, no sabría decir si el error aún persiste.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia pero corta las línea por las palabras y necesito que las corte por caracteres.
No encuentro un control que me permita hacer eso y tampoco se lo suficiente como para hacerlo desde cero.

Comment: TMemo "corta" por palabras, y pediste que funcionase como un TMemo, por eso mi respuesta. Creo que debieras aclarar qué es lo que buscas, en la pregunta, para comenzar.